# How to identify where the error is coming from in redux-saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

New to redux, I am wondering how does one identify the origin if the stack trace just says

```
./src/actions/index.ts
redux-saga-core.esm.js: 1231
redux-saga-core.esm.js: 1231
redux-saga-core.esm.js: 1231
redux-saga-core.esm.js: 1231
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-redux-saga to get stack of your sagas on error.

Comment: @MartinKadlec That helps, is there a solution without adding a babel plugin?

Comment: Using `sourcemaps` ?